# Aerospike AQL Query Against List of Values

Tags: aerospike, aql

In AQL I can do

```
select * from ns.set where PK='some val'
```

How can I query against a list of values? Something like

```
select * from ns.set where PK in ('val1', 'val2'...)
```

When trying to run above code I get 'Unsupported command format'

Comment: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/in-query-on-pk/4158

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not supported in AQL.

Aerospike clients (what you will use in production) support this functionality. Its called Batch Index Read. http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/batch.html

Comment: This is useful for read operations. I didn't included it in the original question but what I really want to do is execute a read-write UDF on the results that match the query.

Comment: you cannot do writes using AQL on a set of records resulting from a secondary index query - you can do reads / aggregations via Stream UDF (AQLs AGGREGATE statement).  stream udf operate in read only mode. record udfs operate on read/write mode.  you can run record udf (AQL's EXECUTE statement) on an individual record or all records in a namespace.[set, optionally].  here is an example of running a record UDF on an entire set - also called running UDF on a scan - https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-delete-a-single-bin-from-set/4519

Comment: Right, in that case is it possible to filter against my list within the udf itself?

Comment: I don't follow your question. can you be more specific - which case, filter on what ...throw me an example. Aerospike has a record level lock on reads or writes. So you can only do one thing at a time on a record - except if you use Operate() - you can modify and read back a  single record in same lock.  For read only, server will accept a set of record keys from you and send you back the results that you can consume in the client. There is subtle difference with results from scan and secondary index query vs batch index read.

Comment: I am referring to a read-write operation. I want to execute a udf only on some records in my set which are predefuned in a list (hence my original question). I can check if a record is valid for my udf in the udf itself as opposed to in the execute statement itself. So if I know the PK of records I want to touch can I filter against this list in the UDF itself and in this case apply the UDF to all records?

Comment: no. record udf needs to know which record its operating on from the client. it cannot act on any other record from within. so you cannot pass it a list of keys and have it operate on multiple records.  you will have to do that from the client. iterate through your list of keys in the client and run record udf on a one record at a time. EXECUTE is interpretted by AQL into a C API call to inovke a record udf on a specific record.   (AQL is just an interactive CLI that parses the input text and converts into C API calls to the server. It is its own syntax!)

Comment: Visiting this old thread, at least now in 2022, with AQL execute, you can run a UDF to modify records which satisfy a secondary index query.  For example, I have records with name and age bins with SI on name.  I can have a UDF that modifies age, for all records where name matches a query value.  e.g. aql> execute modrec.updateAge(5) on test.testset where name = "Sally"  where modrec.lua is: function updateAge(topRec,age_val)
   topRec['age'] = age_val
   aerospike:update(topRec)
   return
end